# A bunch of directories backed up from my previous OS install have setgid permissions, how can I remove it from them?

Tags: macos, permissions

I'm OS X 10.10.1

I just reinstalled my OS, and after restoring the contents of my documents folder from a flash drive, all the directories seem to have setgid permissions because they are showing up in a command prompt with a yellow background.

I have tried `chmod g-s directory_name` `chmod -R g-s directory_name` etc. and the highlighting doesn't seem to go away.

I've looked to see if the syntax for OS X is different, but it doesn't appear to be. What am I doing wrong?

This affects the directories within the directories as well. How can I recursively remove the setgid permissions from all of these folders?

Comment: Can you post an `ls -l` output? What you're doing should work, assuming you really have the problem you think you have.

Comment: All directories have drwxrwxrwx permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the 777 (rwxrwxrwx) mode you're seeing, it is probably highlighting the fact that those files have world/others bits set, which is generally considered bad practice.

I'd suggest setting mode 770 (rwxrwx---) on the directories, and mode 660 (rw-rw----) on documents. Minimally, you should be able to clear the world bits with `chmod -R o-rwx` -- that will however still leave your documents 'executable', which is also bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is there any way I can remove the executability of all my documents after the fact but still leave the directories the way they are?

Comment: Something like `find . -type f -exec chmod a-x {} \;` should do the trick.